# SSO - Permissions Set can't assume Role

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on

I am trying to create a permissions set that will allow me to assume a test role I have created. When I log in however I have no permissions at all. Is there something I am missing on how I should assume this role?

As I understand it permissions sets are roles in themselves and should only contain individual permissions for a specific task. Is it just not possible to assume a role this way using SSO? With the max length of the permission sets it is not feasible for us to put many of our users policies in to one set. Having log in to do one task in S3 then go back out, assume another role to do something with RDS is a pain, hence the idea to assume a role that has all the required perms.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::12341341324:role/test_sso_role"
        }
    ]
}
```

The role just has a number of RO policies for S3/Cloudwatch etc, the trust policy below and no conditions attached.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::12341341324:saml-provider/AWSSSO_a1b2c3d4e5f6g8_DO_NOT_DELETE"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithSAML"
    }
  ]
}
```

Running: aws sts get-caller-identity

```
{  
"UserId": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTU:john.smith@company.com",  
"Account": "12341341324",  
"Arn": "arn:aws:sts::12341341324:assumed-role/AWSReservedSSO_test_sso_role_1a2s3d4f5g6h7j8k/john.smith@company.com"  
}
```